# Visio gantt chart months language

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I've started using MS Visio yesterday to make a gantt chart. Everything is very intuitive for someone used to office but I've been searching for hours on how to change a specific setting on the chart. I have the main units of time as years and the secondary as months. My problem is that the months appear written in my main language and I need them to be written in english. I've tried changing the language of the spell check and the language of the document in the options but it does not work... Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Control Panel -> Region & Language -> Formats**
and select English from the Format drop down list.

That will give you the month names in English. Of course, you'll have to change it back to your own language when you are finished.

Comment: Ah! I see, I have to change the language of the the OS. Thank you very much.